# AWS command runs less every time

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I have a script that is used for inserting data to a db.. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws dynamodb --profile ${PROFILE} put-item --table-name ${TABLE} --item '{"hashKey": {"S":"id1"}, "rangeKey":{"S": "range001"},"info": {"S":"stuff1"}}';
aws dynamodb --profile ${PROFILE} put-item --table-name ${TABLE} --item '{"hashKey": {"S":"id2"}, "rangeKey":{"S": "range002"},"info": {"S":"stuff2"}}';
aws dynamodb --profile ${PROFILE} put-item --table-name ${TABLE} --item '{"hashKey": {"S":"id3"}, "rangeKey":{"S": "range003"},"info": {"S":"stuff3"}}';
aws dynamodb --profile ${PROFILE} put-item --table-name ${TABLE} --item '{"hashKey": {"S":"id4"}, "rangeKey":{"S": "range004"},"info": {"S":"stuff4"}}';
```

The super annoying thing is that for every single line that gets run I get the following, in which I have to manually press 'q' to move onto the next line. **So it appears to somehow be invoking the less command.** [image: annoying script]

I thought it might be a zsh issue but there's not much I am doing there. I am running powerlevel10k. I cannot seem to find a solution online (searching for things like shell command invoking less command) so was hoping someone had run into this before and resolved it...

Comment: Looks like something is invoking `less` on your behalf. Is `aws` an alias by any chance?

Comment: Unless you are asking about interoperability between Bash and Zsh (in which case your question should explicitly do that, obviously) you can't be using both at the same time. Since you mention Zsh I removed the [tag:bash] tag.

Comment: @tripleee re the less, that was my assumption and so I have searched around for that for quite a while but no luck. Re removing the bash tag, I have a problem with something related to a bash script.. Perhaps including zsh in the question was a limiting assumption on my behalf. I've replaced the zsh tag with the bash one, hope that's valid

Comment: Why have you got semicolons at the ends of the lines?

Comment: Try running `type aws` to see what it is really running.

Comment: As a hideous, temporary work-around, you can generate  lots of `q`s with `yes q`, so you could maybe run `yes q | yourScript.bash`

Comment: The variables PROFILE and TABLE are not quoted and so perhaps there is some "noise" in the variables when they are expanded? bash -x will show this if it's the case.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, running 'type aws' made me aware that each line was running aws cli (probably should've been obvious). Have updated with answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer. It wasn't about bash or zsh, and so that's why I wasn't finding a solution.

The issue was with the AWS command as it was running the inserts using AWS CLI. The CLI has a field `AWS_PAGER` which I'm assuming has a default setting of `AWS_PAGER = "less"`.

Whether it's default or not, adding **`export AWS_PAGER=""`** fixed the issue.